# wordpress submit comment by press enter in textarea

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to be able to hide the submit button of WordPress comment form and let users submit their comment by pressing enter and gain new line by pressing Shift+Enter.
i've tried this line of codes at the end of comments.php file in wp theme root file.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $(".PostCommentFormCon textarea").keypress(function (e) {
    if(e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {        
        $(this).closest("form#commentform").submit();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});}
</script>
```

but no chance. 
does any one know how to fix this code ?

Comment: In the console log, what errors do you have?

Comment: no error, when i press Enter Key it goes to new line on textarea input box.
i want to submit the form and replace new line feature with Shif+Enter in text area

Answer (score 0):

If you are set on using a "submit button" You will need to give your submit button an ID:

```
<button style="display:none" id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

And display the button when the user finishes filling out the text area

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".PostCommentFormCon textarea").blur(function (e) {
      if(JQuery.trim(this.val) != ''){
        $("#submitbutton").show();
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="submit Comment">` 
is my button but when i use your code i still get new line in text area when i press enter comment is not submitting, do i have to disable the newline function of text area first or sth ?